# Haskell dynamically transpose multiple lists to single list recursively

Tags: algorithm, haskell

Not sure if "dynamically" is the right word for this problem.

I've been struggling for a while to find a solution for zipping multiple lists
into a single list but I'm starting to think that my approach is not possible.
It works well for two lists but not for three(and probably not with more than three). 
The function is supposed to work as `transpose` but result in a list of integers and
not a list of lists of integers. But if it results in a list of lists it would also 
work. Theoretically, the function is supposed to work for an arbitrary number of lists.

For example [1,2,3] myTranspose [4,5,6] myTranspose [7,8,9] should result in
[1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9]

Is this possiible?

My attempt so far:

```
myTranspose :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
myTranspose [] []         = []
myTranspose [x] []        = [x]
myTranspose [] [y]        = [y] 
myTranspose [x] [y]       = [x,y]
myTranspose (x:xs) [y]    = (x:y:xs)
myTranspose [x] (y:ys)    = (x:y:ys)
myTranspose (x:xs) (y:ys) = [x,y] ++ zip' xs ys
```

EDIT MY ACTUAL PROBLEM:

I should have asked this from the beginning but I thought it would
be simpler to convert the problem to a list of integers. Sorry about that.

I have a data-type `Function` and a function that chains `Function`s
together:

```
data Function where
    (|||) :: Function -> Function -> Function
    A ::  Char -> Function
    B ::  Int  -> Function

chain :: Function -> Function -> Function
chain f1 f2 = f1 ||| f2
```

And I also have a function that is supposed to work like transpose as I described above:

```
(<|||>) :: Funcion -> Function -> Function
 ...something like this..
(<|||>) (p1 ||| p2) (q1 ||| q2)     =  (p1 <|||> q1) ||| (p2 <|||> q2)
(<|||>) (p1 ||| p2)       q          =  p1 <|||> p2 ||| q 
(<|||>)       p         (q1 ||| q2)  =  p  ||| q1 <|||> q2
(<|||>)       p           q          =  p  ||| q
```

I managed to solve the problem using ordinary lists and the ordinary
transpose-function as moonGoose suggested. But the problem is that
the compliler complains about not have enough memory if I do it 
that way.
The function call would look like this, exept the list would be 
very large:

```
transpose ((A 'a' ||| B 5 ||| A 'n')   <|||>  
             (A 'o' ||| B 3 ||| A 'p') <|||>
            (A 'i' ||| B 0 ||| A 'l'))
```

But when I run the program with "my" list-function and an imperfect custom 
transpose-function the compiler don't complain. My thought was that this has to do with laziness. Could that be the issue?
Thank you for helping.

Comment: I think you will have to write distinct versions for 2 vs 3 input lists. This isn't zipping, that's when you take one element from each list at a time instead of alternating from which input you're taking, the name even suggests a helpful implementation trick. `alt [] ys = ys; alt (x:xs) ys = x : alt ys xs` and it's straightforward to see how to extend this to 3+ input lists.

Comment: What's wrong with `concat . transpose` anyway? It would be helpful to provide complete context of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Your specification looks mathematically impossible. It seems to require `[1,2] t [3,4]` to be `[1,3,2,4]`, as well as `[1,3,2,4] t [5,6]` to be `[1,5,3,6,2,4]`, but you also want `([1,2] t [3,4]) t [5,6]` to be `[1,3,5,2,4,6]`, conflicting with the previous result.

Comment: I'm lost. You say "when I run the program with my list-function and an imperfect custom transpose-function the compiler don't complain". Does this mean you have solved your problem? If not, why not? About a different code base, you say "the problem is that the compiler complains about not have enough memory". How can I reproduce this observation myself? I am voting to close, given how vague this is about exactly what problem you are facing, and exactly what code is causing it.

Comment: When I use the "built-in" transpose-function and regular lists the compiler complains about memory with a large amount of chained functions, but the program is correct. I know that the program is correct beacuse it can be run with a small amount of chained functions without the compiler complaining. When I use my attempt for a custom transpose-function and my custom list-function the program is not correct but at least the compiler does not complain about memory for a large amount of chained functions.  ....

Comment: ...So I need to find a solution to a function similar to the transpose-function and it must have the type  `Funcion -> Function -> Function` . Something like  the <|||> function above.

Comment: @moonGoose  Thanks but I don't understand how to extend your `alt`-function. It need to have the type Int -> Int -> Int as yours have. However I can't make it work like this: `[1,2,3] alt [4,5,6] alt [7,8,9] alt [10, 11, 12]` ..........

Comment: @datamoose doesn't your definition of `<|||>` depend on the binding precedence of `|||` vs `<|||>`? It would be helpful to know exactly how you managed to get the memory error.

Comment: @moonGoose I only get the memory-error when I use regular-list and the regular-transpose-function.  I haven't declared any precedence for ||| and <|||> so I guess it defaults to highest precedence and left associativity? I don't think its possible to escape the memory-error with ordinary list and transpose. So I need to have my own list and transpose. Which actually don't create a memory-error for some reason(maybe beacuse of laziness?).  It's just that the custom-transpose messes up the order of the elements.

Comment: @datamoose Telling me you get a memory error is *useless* without saying *exactly what steps to follow to reproduce the memory error*. It could be something in your program, or how you ran it, or anything really if I can't reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you may do like this dynamically

```
zwh :: [[a]] -> [a]
zwh xss = if any ((== 0) . length) xss then []
                                       else hs ++ zwh ts
          where
          (hs,ts) = foldr (\(hs',ts') (rs,qs) -> (hs':rs,ts':qs)) ([],[]) hts
          hts     = (,) <$> head <*> tail <$> xss

λ> zwh [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
[1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9]
λ> zwh [[1,2],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
[1,4,7,2,5,8]
```

or depending on the type `a`, if it is OK to include `EQ a =>` constraint it gets further simplified to

```
zwh :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [a]
zwh xss = if any (== []) xss then []
                             else hs ++ zwh ts
          where
          (hs,ts) = foldr (\(hs',ts') (rs,qs) -> (hs':rs,ts':qs)) ([],[]) hts
          hts     = (,) <$> head <*> tail <$> xss
```

Comment: Thanks but  it must have the type Function -> Function -> Function

Answer (score 0):

After the edit, I think you want something like this? As chi has alluded to already in a comment, it's confusing because it seems that `(|||)` is associative, which is perhaps the core of the issue you're encountering. If it is associative, then the underlying structure is (non-empty-)list-like, so we know how to take the transpose of them and glue them together easily etc. But if it's not associative, then the representation is instead tree-like, and I don't think you can canonically mappend / transpose trees (eg. does `A 0 <> A 1 <> A 2` = `(A 0 ||| A 1) ||| A 2` or `A 0 ||| (A 1 ||| A 2)`? which matters iff `(|||)` is not associative).

```
import Control.Lens.Iso (iso, mapping, under)
import qualified Data.List.NonEmpty as NE
import Data.List.NonEmpty (NonEmpty)
import Data.Semigroup (sconcat)

instance Semigroup Function where
  (<>) = (|||)

transposeFuncs :: NonEmpty Function -> Function
transposeFuncs = sconcat . under (mapping $ iso reify reflect) NE.transpose
  where
    reflect :: Function -> NonEmpty (Either Char Int)
    reflect (a ||| b) = reflect a <> reflect b
    reflect (A a)     = pure $ Left  a
    reflect     (B b) = pure $ Right b
    reify :: NonEmpty (Either Char Int) -> Function
    reify = sconcat . NE.map (either A B)
```

```
transposeFuncs $ NE.fromList 
  [ A 'a' ||| B  5  ||| A 'n'
  , A 'o' ||| B  3  ||| A 'p'
  , A 'i' ||| B  0  ||| A 'l'
  ]
  ==  A 'a' ||| A 'o' ||| A 'i'
  ||| B  5  ||| B  3  ||| B  0
  ||| A 'n' ||| A 'p' ||| A 'l'
```

EDIT:
If you wished to express associativity in the datatype, then you'd use something like the following. See how much better it is when the types match the intent; each (semantic) value has only one representation. If you allowed for an identity then it would be cleaner still.

```
import Control.Lens (makeWrapped, mapping, under, _Unwrapped')
import Data.List.NonEmpty (NonEmpty, transpose)
import Data.Semigroup (sconcat)

data FuncAtom
  = A Char
  | B Int

newtype Function
  = FCompose (NonEmpty FuncAtom)
  deriving Semigroup via NonEmpty FuncAtom
makeWrapped ''Function

transposeFuncs :: NonEmpty Function -> Function
transposeFuncs = sconcat . under (mapping _Unwrapped') transpose
```

Comment: This might work. Will try this as soon as I understand it in detail, thank you.